# Can't INSERT INTO my table via _POST

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert this info into my table `serie` but nothing happens. I guess there's some mistake with the _POST's but i don't know what.

```
$consulta="INSERT INTO `serie` VALUES ('$_POST[id]','$_POST[nombre]','$_POST[genero]', '$_POST[valoracion]','$_POST[director]', '$_POST[reparto]', '$_POST[temporadas]', '$_POST[episodios]', '$_POST[año_emision]', '$_POST[pais]', '$_POST[cadena]', '$_POST[reseña]', '$_POST[trailer]', '$poster_grande')";`
```

**Edit**

I have also tried using

```
$consulta="INSERT INTO `serie` (id, nombre, genero, valoracion, director, reparto, temporadas, episodios, año_emision, pais, cadena, reseña, trailer, poster_grande, poster_pequeño, screenshot1, screenshot2, screenshot3, screenshot4, screenshot5, screenshot6, screenshot7, screenshot8) VALUES ('".$_POST['id']."','".$_POST['nombre']."','$genero', '$valoracion','".$_POST['director']."', '".$_POST['reparto']."', '".$_POST['temporadas']."', '".$_POST['episodios']."', '".$_POST['año_emision']."', '$pais', '".$_POST['cadena']."', '".$_POST['reseña']."', '".$_POST['trailer']."', '$poster_grande', '$poster_pequeño', '$screenshot1' , $screenshot2', '$screenshot3', '$screenshot4', '$screenshot5', '$screenshot6', '$screenshot7', '$screenshot8')";
```

Both with no success.

**Edit**

I found that I was missing a `'`, and the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
$consulta="INSERT INTO `serie` VALUES ('".$_POST['id']."','".$_POST['nombre']."')";
```

You need to put the **keys** of the `$_POST` in **quotes** and better to follow the standard insert query as well like

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1,col2) VALUES (val1,val2)
```

Bec may some conflicts occurs when you have primary keys,auto increments are present in your table.

Comment: I don't think that's it. In a string with double-quotes, you can access an associative array's string keys without using quotes.

Comment: No @willy you need to use quotes in this case or either you need to follow the standard insert query

Comment: Nope. you don't need the quotes in a double-quoted string, php's string interpolation will handle it. [Relevant demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fvw-esp).

Comment: It may differ with the POST and GET variables.Ok I have given another ans too.May be one in both will works..Thanks @willy for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

$consulta = "INSERT INTO `serie` (columnname1,columnname2,columnname3) VALUES (value1,value2,value3)";

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing that anyway - use a prepared statement and bind the `$_POST` data as parameters of that statement.

Here's an example of how to do that using [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/pdo):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO serie VALUES (:id,:nombre,:genero,:valoracion,:director,:reparto,:temporadas,:episodios,:año_emision,:pais,:cadena,:reseña,:trailer,:poster_grande)");

$stmt->execute(array(
    ":id" => $_POST['id'],
    ":nombre" => $_POST['nombre'],
    ":genero" => $_POST['genero'],
    ":valoracion" => $_POST['valoracion'],
    ":director" => $_POST['director'],
    ":reparto" => $_POST['reparto'],
    ":temporadas" => $_POST['temporadas'],
    ":episodios" => $_POST['episodios'],
    ":año_emision" => $_POST['año_emision'],
    ":pais" => $_POST['pais'],
    ":cadena" => $_POST['cadena'],
    ":reseña" => $_POST['reseña'],
    ":trailer" => $_POST['trailer'],
    ":poster_grande" => $poster_grande
));
```